# Workaround to force private access modifier on implemented interface property

Tags: c#, properties, interface

I have and interface as follow:

```
public interface IData
{
    String Name { get; set; }
}
```

And a 2 classes that implements it:

```
public class Data1 : IData
{
    public String Name { get; set; }
}

public class Data2 : IData
{
    public String Name { get; set; }
}
```

I need to prevent getting the Name of a `Data2` instance. The compiler does not allow all following forms:

```
internal String Name { get; set; }
private String Name { get; set; }
public String Name { private get; set; }
```

I do understand the logical reason why this is not explicitly possible. Properties will be accessed using the interface which does not have any clue about implemented access modifiers and will fail if it can't find it.

My use case is that both `Data1` and `Data2` instances should be able to use methods where an `IData` parameter is used (some of the methods where no use of `Name` exist), but `Data2` is sensitive and should not be accessed directly. Therefore I am looking for a workaround.

Comment: You can explicitly implement the interface, meaning that you cannot access the interface member via instances of `Data2` (you must cast to `IData`) but since interfaces are contracts, all methods on them must be public when implemented on a class. You can't use access modifiers when explicitly implementing, but a cast to the interface type makes them accessible (as if they were public)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler doesn't allow the types implementing this interface to change this, because you ask it not to. You defined an interface which has a public getter and setter.

```
public interface IData
{
    String Name { get; set; }
}
```

It sounds like you need two interfaces:

```
public interface ISettableData
{
    String Name { set; }
}

public interface IData : ISettableData
{
    String Name { get; set; }
}
```

And the implementation:

```
public class Data1 : IData
{
    public String Name { get; set; }
}

public class Data2 : ISettableData
{
    public String Name { set; }
}
```

Comment: That is just brilliant :) I can now use ISettableData in the methods parameters

Answer (score 5):

It sounds like you want the access of `Name` through instances of `Data2` to be disallowed.  If that is the case then use an explicit interface implementation

```
public class Data2 : IData {
  String IData.Name { 
    get { ... } 
    set { ... } 
  }
}
```

Now `Name` will only be accessible when `Data2` instances are viewed as `IData`

```
Data2 obj = new Data2();
string name = obj.Name; // Error!
IData other = obj;
name = other.Name;  // Ok
```

Comment: Not exactly what I need but interesting to know. The intention was to prevent access even when using the interface. Check the answer from Cory Nelson